# Why numUnclosedOrphanedConnections in c3p0 increase?

Tags: c3p0

I am using c3p0 (0.9.1.2) version and after a hour or so I see `numUnclosedOrphanedConnections` keep increasing slowly like 1 per hour. c3p0 docs said that

> numUnclosedOrphanedConnections will only be non-zero following a call
>   to softReset(). It represents the number of Connections that were
>   checked out when a soft reset occurred and were therefore silently
>   excluded from the pool, and which remain unclosed by the client
>   application.

Why does c3p0 doing soft reset? My c3p0 settings is like

```
initialPoolSize=1
minPoolSize=1
maxPoolSize=100
maxIdleTime=60
checkoutTimeout=5000
testConnectionOnCheckin=true
```

Comment: what kind of environment are you running in? are you tracking numUnclosedOrphanedConnections vi JMX or programatically? do you ever modify any c3p0 properties? (doing so leads to a softReset() of the pool, so that the modified property values can take.) another thing to look at is how you are close()ing Connections. the monotonic rise of unclosedOrphanedConnections suggests that Connections are being leaked.

Comment: i am running a 64 bit linux machine. Jdk version 1.6.0_31. I am tracking it manually via JMX. c3p0 properties are not modified. Is there a good tool to track connection leak with c3p0?

Comment: yes. see config params unreturnedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces ( see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ ) note you must set BOTH of these properties to get stack traces of leaks. are you embedding c3p0 in your own application, or running using it via a larger library/app server (hibernate, spring, etc)? another thing to do, just to make me feel better, is upgrade to the latest version, c3p0-0.9.2-pre5 i can't remember any issue that would explain your mysterious soft resets, but a lot has changed since 0.9.1

Comment: I am using it with spring (3.0.5). I have set both of those properties and com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool logging level to INFO but I don't see any stacktrace output and the number of unclosedOrphanedConnections still increase. Do you have other reccomendation?

Comment: sean, if you get a chance, please do try the most recent version of c3p0. if you still see the behavior, get in touch by e-mail and i'll try to send you a debug version that dumps stack traces on any softResets, to try to get some sense of why this might be happening. see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ for info on where you can download and how you can find me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Steve for helping me fixing it. This is how I did it.

Enable Debug level logging for c3po:

```
<logger name="com.mchange" additivity="false">
<level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="C3p0Appender" />          
</logger>
```

c3p0 settings:

```
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true
# 30 sec is enough for me but you should change it for your case
unreturnedConnectionTimeout=30
```

And the keyword to search inside c3p0 log file is: "Overdue resource check-out "

This logging is only enable in the trunk version of c3p0. It should be there in pre6 release.